# Compare Trigger vs. Workflow Rule vs. Process Builder

Tags: trigger, workflow, process-builder

Give an example of why you would use a trigger over a workflow or process builder to accomplish an update to a field?

Comment: Hi Reddy and welcome to SFSE. Your last couple of questions both (a) do not really fit our format and (b) have the form, whether or not it's your intent, of an interview or exam-style question. Please take the SFSE [Tour] and read [ask] to understand what is on topic here.

Comment: I've downvoted this question because it shows no research effort, and (as David Reed mentioned) it also sounds like an interview or exam question. Answering this for you with the question in its current state would defeat the purpose (which is to find out if _you_ know the answer, not if someone else can do your work for you)

Answer (score 2):

Process builders are meant to replace workflow rules. They aren't meant to replace triggers.

Workflows vs. PB

> Process Builder lets you automate more things.
>
> Process Builder lets you control the order of your criteria.
>
> Process Builder lets you access fields on every related record.
>
> Process Builder is the future.

Here is a trailhead with more documentation - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/workflow_migration/workflow_migration_intro

For PB vs. Triggers

I use Triggers when I need bulkification and it needs to be bulletproof. Also, when I need fine tuned error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to PartOfTheOhana points.

Salesforce encourages "no code only click" slogan and emphasizes to use workflow or process builder first then if requirement is not achievable then use trigger.

For your use case, we can use workflow/PB to update field instead of trigger. But there may be performance issue in ***some complex org*** where each workflow field update/PB ***will cause a DML*** and will execute the whole execution cycle once more - due to an extra execution of whole cycle, more SOQL (agains limit of 100) and more DMLs (agains limit of 150) and so on ..

But putting same field update in trigger in *before update/before insert* will not cause a DML and will not cause an extra execution.

Answer (score 0):

Use workflow if you need to do the below:

1- send outbound message without coding 
2- need to update the same record fields or parent record fields (one level only)
3- need to create tasks (not other objects) 
4- when you dont care about the order of the workflows

user process when:

1- you need to preform it with order
2- when you need to send approval or post to chatter
3- create any object
4- update records related to your cussrent record no matter how far is the releationship is

use flow for more complex requirements.